# jquery this and other elements

Tags: jquery, this

OK, going rond in circles again - I'm sure the answer will be obvious. Just not to me :)

I can't seem to specify **this** as one target amongst a few targets for a function:

```
$(this, "elem1, elem2").doStuff()
```

I just want to doStuff() to a pair of elements, one of which is **this**. I can only get it to work if I explicitly name the elements, ie...

```
$("elem1, elem2, elem3").doStuff()
```

...works fine. But I can't seem to get it to work if I want to include **this** in the list. I have to write one line just for **this**, and another for elem1 elem2 etc.

All help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 'Jquery - This and Other Elements' would be a great title for a book...

Comment: :) Gerald Durrell for the Jquery generation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to add `this` to the jQuery object:

```
$("#elem1, #elem2").add(this).doStuff();
```

Or in reverse:

```
$(this).add("#elem1, #elem2").doStuff();
```

or even:

```
$(this).add("#elem1").add("#elem2").doStuff();
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch - I knew it would be straightforward enough.